# Getting the updated state data in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am facing a problem with getting the updated `state` data in a functional component. I have seen threads on SO where it is recommended to switch to a Class component where states can be managed better without the use of hooks but I feel like same should be possible with hooks in a functional component.

My code is as follows

```
function HomePage(){
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
    const [locationOptions, setLocationOptions] = useState([
        {label: 'Location 1', value: 'location-1'},
        {label: 'Location 2', value: 'location-2'},
        {label: 'Location 3', value: 'location-3'},
    ]);


    // Getting the data from the servers and updating the state
    // works fine in the render, the data gets updated
    const { data: locationData, refetch: locationDataRefetch } = useAppQuery({
        url: "/api/get-locations", 
        reactQueryOptions: {
            onSuccess: async ( e ) => {
              if ( e.data ) {
                setLocationOptions( e.data );
              } else {
                // handle errors
              }
            },
          },
      });

    
    const seeUpdatedLocations = () => {
        // This is where the problem is, even after the state is updated after getting
        // the data from the API, this still logs the initial value of locationOptions
        console.log( locationOptions );
    }


    const handleSelectChange = useCallback((value) => {
        // This is where the problem is, even after the state is updated after getting
        // the data from the API, this still logs the initial value of locationOptions
        // value can be 'location-1', and I use lodash to get the right object from locationOptions
        let selectedLocationObj = _.find( locationOptions, ( o ) => o.value == value );

        console.log( selectedLocationObj ); // Doesn't work as the locationOptions doesn't contain the real values received from API

    }, []);


    return (

        <Select
                label="Location"
                options={locationOptions}
                onChange={ handleSelectChange }
                value={ selected.value }
                labelHidden={true}
        />

    );



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) (emphasis mine):

> Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. `useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback **that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed**. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. `shouldComponentUpdate`).

The dependency array of your `useCallback` is empty, this means that the function is never updated, so you always get the initial values. Adding `locationOptions` as a dependency should solve your problem.

You should also ask yourself if this `useCallback` is necessary. Here is [a great article](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#memoize-everything) about that.

Comment: I am speechless. It's a Sunday and I have been working on this since the morning, and now it's finally solved, thanks to you!